# Authenticate to Kafka from a different AD domain using keytab

Tags: apache-kafka, active-directory, sssd

Trying to authenticate between two different AD domains using a keytab, in order to read from a Kafka topic.

So system A has AD domain A, a valid user/keytab in domain A etc, a valid sentry role, a Kafka topic, consumer group etc.

System B is in AD domain B, and the keytab from system A.

Is there anyway to read from the Kafka topic? If I had the system A AD domain details into the system B krb5.conf file, I can see the topic. When I remove it, it fails. Our experiment is to do this without allowing system B to contact our kdc however.

Is there anyway to do this? We've tried using Java and scala.

Comment: You will need (at least) a one-way trust configured between your realms. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-does-a-cross-realm-trust-work/ta-p/245705

Comment: Yes, that’s what we’re finding. I was assured by an architect that it ws possible, but nothing is working yet. Just thought I’d ask if anyone has solved it. I was pointed to some Confluent doco, but that all assumes you’re in the same realm.

Comment: Its being done everywhere all the time :) Your AD admins should just follow the config guide.